# Python shapely difference between polygon and a collection of circles not working properly

Tags: python, polygon, difference, shapely

I am trying to measure the vacancies within a cluster of circles.
A vacancy is a empty area whose surface area is bigger than a target area
The algorithm I am targeting should work like this:

1. I first define circles with coordinates x,y.
2. Then I define the convex hull enveloping the circles cluster.
3. I unify the circles then subtract them from the convex hull.
4. I identify vacancies with a surface area bigger than a target area and discard the rest (fill them as the background color.

To help with this exercise, I am plotting each time the result.

This is a test code that I wrote:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("qt5agg")
def generate_hexagonal_grid(side_length, diameter):
    points = []
    radius = diameter / 2
    vertical_distance = np.sqrt(3) * radius
    x_max = side_length * np.cos(np.pi / 6)

    # Creating a hexagonal grid of points within the hexagon
    row = 0
    while (row * vertical_distance) < (2 * x_max):
        if row % 2 == 0:
            x_offset = diameter
        else:
            x_offset = radius

        x = -x_max + x_offset

        while x < x_max:
            y = -x_max + row * vertical_distance
            if np.abs(y) <= x_max:
                points.append((x, y))
            x += diameter

        row += 1

    return points


def draw_flat_topped_hexagon(apothem):
    s = 2 * apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6)
    vertices = [
        (-apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), apothem),
        (apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), apothem),
        (2 * apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), 0),
        (apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), -apothem),
        (-apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), -apothem),
        (-2 * apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), 0)
    ]
    hexagon = Polygon(vertices)
    return hexagon
def fill_hexagon_with_circles(hexagon, points):
    # Initialize a plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    # Set the background color of the plot to black
    ax.set_facecolor('black')

    # List to store circle geometries
    circles = []
    occupied_area_center = []

    # Plot circles within the hexagon with black color
    i = 0
    for x, y in points:

        if i!=int(len(points)/2):
            point = Point(x, y)
            circle = point.buffer(0.5)  # Circle with diameter 1
            if circle.centroid not in occupied_area_center:
                if hexagon.contains(circle):
                    occupied_area_center.append(circle.centroid)
                    circles.append(circle)
                    x, y = circle.exterior.xy
                    ax.fill(x, y, alpha=1, fc='yellow', edgecolor='black')
        i+=1
    occupied_area = unary_union(circles)
    
    # Create a polygon that surrounds the circles by creating a convex hull
    surrounding_polygon = unary_union(circles).convex_hull

    # Calculate the surface area of a bead
    bead_area = math.pi * (0.5) ** 2

    # Calculate the target area
    max_packing_fraction = math.pi / (2 * math.sqrt(3))
    target_area = bead_area / max_packing_fraction
    vacant_space = surrounding_polygon.difference(occupied_area)
    vacant_areas = list(polygonize(vacant_space.boundary))
    valid_vacancies = [poly for poly in vacant_areas if poly.area > target_area]
    total_vacant_area = sum(poly.area for poly in valid_vacancies)
    for i, vacancy in enumerate(valid_vacancies):
        x, y = vacancy.exterior.xy
        ax.fill(x, y, alpha=0.5, fc='red', label=f'Vacancy {i + 1}')
    plt.show()


hex_diameter = 12
circle_diameter = 1.0

# Calculate the side length of the hexagon
side_length = hex_diameter * np.sqrt(3) / 2

# Generate a grid of points within the hexagon
points = generate_hexagonal_grid(side_length, circle_diameter)

# Create hexagon and fill it with circles
hexagon = draw_flat_topped_hexagon(hex_diameter)
fill_hexagon_with_circles(hexagon, points)
```

The outcome looks like this:
[image]
I was expecting something more like this:
[image]

An important piece of information: to generate the desired outcome I modified this line:
`circle = point.buffer(0.5)  # Circle with diameter 1` 
to
`circle = point.buffer(0.501)  # Circle with diameter 1`

These are fake positions, the actual positions would be more distant, so this trick would not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that many/some adjacent vacant areas stay connected and so their area is combined...

To avoid this, I would look for a structured way to subdivide the "vacant area" in logical parts.

I gave it a try by using delaunay triangles based on the middle points of the circles, and this way it is possible to get to your expected result:

```
import shapely
import shapely.plotting as sh_plot
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString, MultiPoint, Polygon, Point
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.use("qt5agg")


def generate_hexagonal_grid(side_length, diameter):
    points = []
    radius = diameter / 2
    vertical_distance = np.sqrt(3) * radius
    x_max = side_length * np.cos(np.pi / 6)

    # Creating a hexagonal grid of points within the hexagon
    row = 0
    while (row * vertical_distance) < (2 * x_max):
        if row % 2 == 0:
            x_offset = diameter
        else:
            x_offset = radius

        x = -x_max + x_offset

        while x < x_max:
            y = -x_max + row * vertical_distance
            if np.abs(y) <= x_max:
                points.append((x, y))
            x += diameter

        row += 1

    return points


def draw_flat_topped_hexagon(apothem):
    s = 2 * apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6)
    vertices = [
        (-apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), apothem),
        (apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), apothem),
        (2 * apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), 0),
        (apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), -apothem),
        (-apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), -apothem),
        (-2 * apothem * math.tan(math.pi / 6), 0),
    ]
    hexagon = Polygon(vertices)
    return hexagon


def fill_hexagon_with_circles(hexagon, points):
    # Initialize a plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # Set the background color of the plot to black
    ax.set_facecolor("black")

    # List to store circle geometries
    circles = []
    occupied_area_center = []

    # Plot circles within the hexagon with black color
    i = 0
    for x, y in points:
        if i != int(len(points) / 2):
            point = Point(x, y)
            circle = point.buffer(0.5)  # Circle with diameter 1
            if circle.centroid not in occupied_area_center:
                if hexagon.contains(circle):
                    occupied_area_center.append(circle.centroid)
                    circles.append(circle)
                    x, y = circle.exterior.xy
                    ax.fill(x, y, alpha=1, fc="yellow", edgecolor="black")
        i += 1
    occupied_area = unary_union(circles)

    # Create a polygon that surrounds the circles by creating a convex hull
    surrounding_polygon = unary_union(circles).convex_hull

    # Calculate the surface area of a bead
    bead_area = math.pi * (0.5) ** 2

    # Calculate the target area
    max_packing_fraction = math.pi / (2 * math.sqrt(3))
    target_area = bead_area / max_packing_fraction
    vacant_space = surrounding_polygon.difference(occupied_area)

    # Subdivide the vacant space using delaunay triangles. The target area needs to
    # be divided by the number of triangles
    delaunays = shapely.get_parts(shapely.delaunay_triangles(MultiPoint(points)))
    vacant_areas = shapely.intersection(vacant_space, delaunays)
    # vacant_areas = list(polygonize(vacant_space.boundary))
    target_area /= 6

    # Plot points and delaunay edges to illustrate what is happening
    # delaunay_edges = shapely.delaunay_triangles(MultiPoint(points), only_edges=True)
    # sh_plot.plot_line(MultiLineString(delaunay_edges), color="green")
    # sh_plot.plot_points(MultiPoint(points), color="orange")

    # Only retain sufficiently large areas
    valid_vacancies = [poly for poly in vacant_areas if poly.area > target_area]
    total_vacant_area = sum(poly.area for poly in valid_vacancies)
    for i, vacancy in enumerate(valid_vacancies):
        x, y = vacancy.exterior.xy
        ax.fill(x, y, alpha=0.5, fc="red", label=f"Vacancy {i + 1}")
    plt.show()


hex_diameter = 12
circle_diameter = 1.0

# Calculate the side length of the hexagon
side_length = hex_diameter * np.sqrt(3) / 2

# Generate a grid of points within the hexagon
points = generate_hexagonal_grid(side_length, circle_diameter)

# Create hexagon and fill it with circles
hexagon = draw_flat_topped_hexagon(hex_diameter)
fill_hexagon_with_circles(hexagon, points)
```

For illustration, the orange points are the points, the green lines are the delauynay triangles used to subdivide the vacant area. As you see, the larger vacant area is subdivided in 6 parts, this is why I divide target_area by 6.

[image]